# How to cite a paragraph from a paper with a citation in it

Tags: citations, paper-submission, citation-style

In my paper, I want to cite a paragraph from another paper that looks like this:

> Universities are an ideal target for attackers because they have high bandwidth and open systems.“A university is not a high security area,” says Andreas Pfitzmann, professor for data security at the Technische Universität, Dresden.

How can I do that citation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you would switch between double and single ticks for the outer and inner quotation, respectively.

Alternatively, for a quotation of the length you are showing, consider using a (slightly indented) quotation block.

*I will look for some examples when I have a stable connection again.*

Of course, you should also check the styleguide of your target venue, although in my experience, paper styleguides rarely mention such details/special cases.

Comment: Yes, i've never seen suck specific case... Thank you !